# Undefined local variable in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

undefined local variable or method `dashboard_user' for #
Extracted source (around line #3):

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
def user_creation
dashboard_user.create(:username => params[:username])
dashboard_user.create(:password => params[:password])
dashboard_user.create(:lastname => params[:lastname])
dashboard_user.create(:firstname => params[:firstname])
```

how do i fix this thanks i am new to ruby

After fixing this i am getting this
undefined method `attr_accessible' for

```
class DashboardUser < ActiveRecord::Base
self.table_name = "dashboard_user"
attr_accessible :username
attr_accessible :password
attr_accessible :lastname
attr_accessible :firstname
```

full controller

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def user_creation
     DashboardUser.create(:username => params[:username])
     DashboardUser.create(:password => params[:password])
     DashboardUser.create(:lastname => params[:lastname])
     DashboardUser.create(:firstname => params[:firstname])
     DashboardUser.create(:middlename => params[:middlename])
     DashboardUser.create(:phone => params[:phone])
    redirect_to :action => 'user_creation'
  end
  private
  def dashboard_params
  params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:id, :username, :password, :lastname, :firstname, :middlename , :phone)
  end
end

create_table "dashboard_user", primary_key: "USER_ID", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "USER_NAME",            limit: 50,  null: false
    t.string   "NORMALIZED_USER_NAME", limit: 50
    t.string   "PASSWORD",             limit: 50
    t.string   "LAST_NAME",            limit: 50
    t.string   "FIRST_NAME",           limit: 50
    t.string   "MIDDLE_NAME",          limit: 50
    t.string   "PHONE",                limit: 15
    t.string   "EMAIL_ID",             limit: 100
    t.integer  "SEQ_QUES_ID"
    t.string   "SEQ_QUES_ANSWER",      limit: 100
    t.string   "EXPIRE_PASSWORD_IND",  limit: 1
    t.date     "EXPIRE_PASSWORD_DATE"
    t.string   "DEACTIVATED_IND",      limit: 1
    t.date     "DEACTIVATED_DATE"
    t.integer  "ROLE_ID"
    t.string   "CREATED_BY",           limit: 50
    t.datetime "CREATED_DATE"
    t.string   "UPDATED_BY",           limit: 50
    t.datetime "UPDATED_DATE"
  end
```

schema

Comment: You don't need to have attr accessible on each line, declare it once and then comma separate the attributes

Comment: but it says attr_accessible undefined method or variable

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: so you should be using permitted_params then as its rails 4

Comment: params.require(:create).permit(:username, :password, :lastname, :firstname, :middlename ,:phone) like this in controller?

Comment: change params.require(:create) to params.require(:dashboard_user), get rid of attr_accessible

Comment: redirect_to :action => 'user_creation'
    params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:username, :password, :lastname, :firstname, :middlename ,:phone)
  end
end this is my new controller ending

Comment: how do i change this ? to make it accessible my DB table has USER_NAME as field name does it have anything to do with this

Comment: put your complete admin controller code in your question please and also the dashboard_user schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On important rule in Rails is: Convention over Configuration

In convention your model file called **dashboard_user** but when you open that file, your model class name should be **DashboardUser** so following change to your code should solve the problem:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

    def user_creation
       DashboardUser.create(:username => params[:username])
       DashboardUser.create(:password => params[:password])
       DashboardUser.create(:lastname => params[:lastname])
       DashboardUser.create(:firstname => params[:firstname])

    end

end
```

Comment: thanks that solved my controller issue but now i am getting the issue that i am getting above in my question

Comment: You can create them one at a time.`DashboardUser.create(:username => params[:username],:password => params[:password],:lastname => params[:lastname],:firstname => params[:firstname])`

Comment: i got the controller issue solved but getting a issue in my model part

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you should be using the new permitted_params (As your using Rails 4)

It should look like this at the bottom of your controller

```
private

def dashboard_params
  params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:id, :user_name, :first_name, :last_name, :password)
end
```

Comment: class DashboardUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "dashboard_user"
end

Comment: this is my model now .. and my controller is private
  def dashboard_params
  params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:id, :username, :password, :lastname, :firstname, :middlename , :phone)
  end but still same error

Comment: why have you got self.table_name = "dashboard_user"  ??

Comment: how are you creating a dashboard user, do you have a form where a user inputs their details (params), do you have CRUD setup in your controller?? what are you trying to do ?

Comment: i have a form to get the params from and self.table_name because i already have a table called dashboard_user

Comment: post your controller in the question please

Comment: added the full controller

Comment: you need schema.rb as well?

Comment: can i ask why all your columns are in capital letters ?

Comment: ive made an edit to my answer as your field names are using underscores, try it, though i wouldnt have everything in capital letters

Comment: using USER_NAME works :) but in the  DashboardUser.create(:username => params[:username]) as  DashboardUser.create(:USER_NAME => params[:username])

Comment: Field 'USER_NAME' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `dashboard_user` VALUES () after that getting this error

Comment: why aren't you using CRUD?

Comment: I am just starting rails so i dont know .. Ill look into crud . will it work with mysql remote DB?